# Operating System Development

Tags: operating-system

I'm looking for any website(s) devoted and/or related to Operating System Development, and would love for you to kindly share any links you may have.

I have searched myself, but keep winding up at the same old sites, and am wondering if there are others that just don't get noticed by the major search engines or something.

I've put this as a community wiki, simply because I don't think it's very fair to judge an answer based on a single link.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you looking for specifically?  Developing a new OS for common hardware?  Porting an existing OS to new hardware?  Asking for OS development sites is like asking for websites on application development.

Comment: Nothing in particular. I'm looking at developing an operating system. I'm sorry to be so vague, but I really am not expecting anything in particular, I just want to get as much variety as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest a book, rather than any website.  There are a number of good ones:

- Operating Systems: Design and Implementation (Tanenbaum)
- Modern Operating Systems (Tanenbaum)
- Operating System Concepts (Silberschatz & Galvin)
- Unix Systems for Modern Architectures (Schimmel)

Once you understand the concepts, you can start to design and develop for your particular project.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a couple of books:

[Developing Your Own 32-Bit Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672306557)

[Dissecting DOS: A Code-Level Look at the DOS Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020162687X)

Reading these will give you an idea of how an operating system is built and the amount of work it takes to build one.

Here's one website with a tutorial walkthrough: http://www.brokenthorn.com/

(Googling 'operating system development tutorial' reveals several but most seem to be dead ends or links to Linux.)

Answer (score 0):

How about a wiki? There's the [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).